# Автозаполнение поля JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть два поля человек и адрес, когда пользователь вводит в поле человек, то необходимо ajax запросом обратится к БД и подставить в поле адрес адрес этого человека, вот что сейчас я сделал

```
 $.ajax({                                      
  url: '../autoCompliteForms.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
  data: "q="+$(".fio_students").val(),                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                   //for example "id=5&parent=6"
  dataType: 'json',                //data format      
  success: function(data) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".adres").val(data["adres"]);
    });

}

} 
);
```

JS обращается в PHP скрипту, который отдаёт Json, в Firebug я вижу, что ответ приходит6 но почему-то не подставляется в html-поле.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас же Ajax, событие `$(document).ready(function(){` уже не будет происходить после загрузки страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите из кода вот эту обертку:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...
});
```

Вы неправильно её используете. Она должна оборачивать ВЕСЬ ваш код, так чтобы он запустился в браузере только после того, как страница загрузит весь DOM.

В итоге код должен выглядеть как то так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // другой код

    $.ajax({                                      
        url: '../autoCompliteForms.php',
        data: "q="+$(".fio_students").val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $(".adres").val(data["adres"]);
        }
    });

    // другой код
});
```